# HTML <label> Ambiguity (mainly in my own brain)...? Could someone clarify?

Tags: html, label

I've been doing quite a bit of work recently with form elements, in particular trying to best apply more semantic markup to my form layout, so that I can provide easily styleable forms with little or no extraneous markup such as divs, spans etc which offer little extra meaning to the form, in a semantic sense.

After using the label as a housing element for both input and title of element, I've noticed that there seems to be some ambiguity (in my own mind at least - please feel absolutely free to clarify the point if possible) regarding its use in terms of normal inputs and radio/check arrays.

If I can explain with a brief example...

```
<label>Amount<input type='text' name='amount' value='1' /></label>
```

The above code is fair enough. The label tag encapsulates both the form element and label text 'Amount' giving meaning to the title in the context of it being the label for the input. That seems fine... yeah?

but consider the following radio sets...

```
SET A:    
<label>Colour
<span><input type='radio' name='colour' value='red' />Red</span> 
<span><input type='radio' name='colour' value='white' />Blue</span>
<span><input type='radio' name='colour' value='blue' />White</span>
</label>


SET B:    
<span>Colour
<label><input type='radio' name='colour' value='red' />Red</label> 
<label><input type='radio' name='colour' value='white' />Blue</label>
<label><input type='radio' name='colour' value='blue' />White</label>
</span>
```

*Please note the use of `<span>` as an encapsulation element in both cases is purely incidental, and could be any element realistically.*

I'm tending to err on the side of SET A myself, as I would sort of think the entire radio/check box array/set as a whole would the part of the markup that would require the label tag in a contextual sense, but does anyone have any thoughts they can throw into the mix with this one?

---

After looking at the [microformat spec](http://microformats.org/wiki/product-examples) (unfinished as with the rest of the web)  I'm looking at using p-v pairing for provision of colour (or any other set/array) info. To this end my original SET A outline should suffice in providing both the rendered and spidered views of the page with all the necessary hierarchical info I'd be wanting to properly categorise these snippets of info I think.

I'm perhaps looking at going down this road at the moment. (Please point out any glaring stupidity please)

```
SET A [revised]:    
<somecontainerparentelement class="hproduct">
<label "p-v"><em class="property">Colour</em>
<span><input type='radio' name='colour' value='red' /><em class="value">Red</em></span> 
<span><input type='radio' name='colour' value='white' /><em class="value">Blue</em></span>
<span><input type='radio' name='colour' value='blue' /><em class="value">White</em></span>
</label>
</somecontainerparentelement>
```

Sort of issue with this method is that I'm unsure whether the p-v will allow the existance of a single Parameter (ie the `<em>Colour</em>`) with multiple Values (ie the `class='value'` elements within `<labels>`).

Although the non issue with it would be that I don't have to lose any sleep, hair or teeth trying to style a legend in IE (I assume the loss of teeth from banging my face against my desk and keyboard)...

Answer (score 5):

What I would do there is this...

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Colour</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colour" value="red" />Red</label> 
    <label><input type="radio" name="colour" value="white" />Blue</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colour" value="blue" />White</label>
</fieldset>
```

Also, you can have your `label` element separate and link its `for` attribute to the `id` attribute of the element. It generally makes styling them easier IMO.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Colour</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="red" id="colour-red" />
    <label for="colour-red">Red</label> 
    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="white" id="colour-white" />
    <label for="colour-white">White</label>
    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="blue" id="colour-blue" />
    <label for="colour-blue">Blue</label>
</fieldset>
```

Note that the `legend` element is notoriously difficult to style cross browser.

Comment: I like your solution. I think you should include the `label for` variant in your example.

Comment: @nfechner Way ahead of you :)

Comment: I had already sort of eliminated fieldset to be honest but cheers for the suggestion. My feeling is that fieldset is more use in 'sectioning' or delimiting a form into it's constituent components, so I was trying to kind of hold back on using that tag in this context. Suppose for small forms it may make sense though. Also I did already try this in code and IE almost puked while trying to position the legend... lol

Comment: @BizNuge *My feeling is that fieldset is more use in 'sectioning' or delimiting a form into it's constituent components* -> That is exactly what I am doing above, I am grouping the radio buttons, labels and heading in a `fieldset`.

Comment: Fair comment. although IE is still absolute erse in terms of the legend styling ( I'm currently trying to position the control title to the left of the the radios... nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML5 draft spec specifically covers the SET A situation. [It says:](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/forms.html#the-label-element)

> If the for attribute is not specified,
>   but the label element has a labelable
>   form-associated element descendant,
>   then the first such descendant in tree
>   order is the label element's labeled
>   control.

Which means that

```
<label>Colour
  <span><input type='radio' name='colour' value='red' />Red</span> 
  <span><input type='radio' name='colour' value='white' />White</span>
  <span><input type='radio' name='colour' value='blue' />Blue</span>
</label>
```

is *semantically* equivalent to

```
<label>Colour
  <span><input id="control1" type='radio' name='colour' value='red' />Red</span>
</label> 
<span>
   <input id="control2" type='radio' name='colour' value='white' />
   <label for="control1">White</label>
</span>
<span>
   <input id="control3" type='radio' name='colour' value='blue' />
   <label for="control1">Blue</label>
</span>
```

which isn't what I think you intend.

This also has practical consequences. If you put that markup on a web page, and then click the words "White" or "Blue", in some browsers it will result in the 'Red' radio button being selected.

Ideally, Alex's solution would be used, but as you've found, styling `legend` is a PITA. There are some workarounds but nothing wholly satisfactory IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is usually to connect the elements using the id:

```
<input id="test1" type="text"/><label for="test1">Test 1</label>
<input id="test2" type="text"/><label for="test2">Test 2</label>
```

Comment: not too fussed on the id solution, although I admit, it would seem to be an actual solution to the problem, at least in terms of rendering. What I'm hopefully trying to provide eventually though, is a holistic solution that both works well in the browser, but also work s in the context of spidering/crawling, eventually with microformat info too, so parent->children relationships and nesting is something I'd like to incorporate to a large degree.